# Text popping through on image replacement

Tags: css

I've used a standard image replacement technique for one of my links, (the nested span technique) but as the image is round & transparent at the edges, the underlying text link is popping through.

Heres my screenshot that explains what I mean.

http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/240752/peepo.gif

Whats the best way to hide this text? I don't want to use `display:none` as its bad practice, and I had a feeling that setting the text size to 0 is also a no-no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to employ another image replacement techique, e.g. give the text a very large `text-indent` value. Refer to [Mezzoblue](http://www.mezzoblue.com/tests/revised-image-replacement/) for a comprehensive list of techniques along with their trade-offs.

Alternatively, you could provide the `display: none` property in the `@media screen` section of the stylesheet. This means it shouldn't get applied for screen readers (since these should be of media type `aural`). However, I can't verify if current screen readers really have this (expected) behaviour.